# NotifyIcon does not display

Tags: c#, winforms, notifyicon

I'm trying to display a notifyIcon but it's not working.

Why does nothing appear?

```
public void notify_icon(string text, string title)
{
    var notify = new NotifyIcon() 
    {
        Icon = this.Icon,
        BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info,
        BalloonTipTitle = title,
        BalloonTipText = text,
    };
    notify.ShowBalloonTip(2000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Visibility `true`. Reference [NotifyIcon Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var notify = new NotifyIcon() 
    {
        Icon = this.Icon,
        BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info,
        BalloonTipTitle = title,
        BalloonTipText = text,
        Visible = true,
    };
```